# Android Tabhost multiple activities in tab, onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-tabhost, android-navigation

I'll describe my problem.
I'm using `tabhost` in my android app, and i have `tree tabs` in it. First and third is "normal", which means - one activity per one tab.
The second tab isn't like others. I want to use two activities in it and it  extends `ActivityGroup`.
Use case:
User tapped into second tab > `SettingsActivity` is opened > User saved settings (button) > `ActionActivity` is opened.
I'm using this code for calling `ActionActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActionActivity.class);
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("activity_action", intent);
    setContentView(window.getDecorView());
```

And it works. Tab changes to `ActionActivity`.
The problem is with `Java#onBackPressed()` method. I'm catching it in `SettingsActivity`. I want go back from `ActionActivity` to `Settings Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    Activity view = manager.getCurrentActivity();

    if ((view instanceof ActionActivity)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        replaceContentView("activity_settings", intent);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

I can't catch this event in `ActionActivity`.

This method wroks, but... only once.

Use case:
`SettingsActivity` > `ActionActivity` > BackPressed > `SettingsActivity` > `ActionActivity` > BackPressed > app is shutting down.

When I'm debugging `if ((view instanceof ActionActivity))` at first time it gets true, but at the second time it gets false, so the app is shutting down.
Can you help me? Have you any idea how to solve it?

Use case of app should be:
`SettingsActivity` > `ActionActivity` > BackPressed > `SettingsActivity` > `ActionActivity` > BackPressed > `SettingsActivity` > `ActionActivity` > BackPressed > `SettingsActivity` > etc.

Regards.

Comment: using back button to switch tabs is against android's ui rules (maybe you need some kind wizard control)... second, using activities as tab's pages was deprecated ages ago